# Залить Pandas df в Google sheets через API

Tags: python, pandas, google-spreadsheet

Вроде все работает но вот когда я пытаюсь записать df в новый лист 'sheet' то получаю ошибку.

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from df2gspread import df2gspread as d2g

# Specify path to your file with credentials

path_to_credential = 'путь.json'

# Specify name of table in google sheets

table_name = 'py-to-google'


scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(path_to_credential, scope)

gs = gspread.authorize(credentials)
work_sheet = gs.open(table_name)

# Select 1st sheet
sheet1 = work_sheet.sheet1

# Get data in python lists format
data = sheet1.get_all_values()

# Get header from data
headers = data.pop(0)

# Create df
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)

spreadsheet_name = 'py-to-google'

sheet = 'py-to-google'


d2g.upload(df, spreadsheet_name, sheet, credentials=credentials, row_names=True)
```

```
/var/folders/wv/j__1xb_j3bjctrgyln3pnt7m0000gn/T/ipykernel_5022/1142499611.py:3: DeprecationWarning: [Deprecated][in version 6.0.0]: client_factory will be replaced by gspread.http_client types
  d2g.upload(df, spreadsheet_name, sheet, credentials=credentials, row_names=True)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/df2gspread/df2gspread.py:138: FutureWarning: DataFrame.applymap has been deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.
  df = df.applymap(str)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/df2gspread/df2gspread.py:138: FutureWarning: DataFrame.applymap has been deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.
  df = df.applymap(str)

<Worksheet 'py-to-google' id:2069214263>
```